# ANOVA or survival analysis in this experiment?

Tags: anova, survival, kaplan-meier

I have performed the following experiment but I am not sure what statistical analysis perform.

The aim is to test if a drug is lethal on a fish species. For this, I have 3 tanks with 10 fish in each tank. Each tank receives a treatment (control, low drug concentration or high drug concentration). The variable measured is the % mortality of each group (or tank) at 3, 6 and 9 days. I have 3 tank by trt, so I have 3 samples.

I originally wanted to run an ANOVA (2 factors: trt and time), but I doubt the independence of the data, as I am measuring mortality on the same population group (or tank).

Therefore, I am considering either a two-factor (treatment and time) repeated measures ANOVA or a kaplan-meier survival analysis.

What do you think? Any advice would be of great help to me.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard ANOVA requires a continuous outcome. You don't have that. You are evaluating binary dead/alive event outcomes, with not all individuals  necessarily experiencing an event over the period of observation ("right-censored" event times). That calls for some type of survival analysis.

With only 3 observation times, however, the continuous-time survival analysis represented by methods like Kaplan-Meier curves don't work so well. "Survival analysis" in this situation can be set up simply as a binomial regression (e.g., logistic regression) that evaluates the probability of death within each time period as a function of the drug treatment.

Comment: I proposed ANOVA since my variable is a %, and therefore I think I could fit it to a continuous distribution. However, the aspect that worries me about is the non-dependence of the data. Do you think it could be an approximation, even if it is not the best one (dependent measures ANOVA)?

As you proposed, I think binomial regression would be more appropriate, as even if I have the percentage, I can extract the information in 0 and 1 for each individual. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Miquel the other problem with using ANOVA on percentage outcomes is that the residuals in the model typically don't have the normal distribution that ANOVA assumes. Binomial regression gets around that. For non-dependence, it depends on the experimental design. If you only have 1 tank per treatment, then you can't separate tank-specific effects from treatment-specific effects. If you have multiple tanks per treatment, then you could treat the tanks as random effects in a binomial mixed model (`glmer()` in R) to account for within-tank correlations in outcomes.